# mathematical accurate definition of the binary independence model

Tags: nlp, probability, information-retrieval

I have a hard time understanding the exact mathematical meaning behind the binary independence model. On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Independence_Model) we can see the following definition  or similarly in the [book](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/the-binary-independence-model-1.html) from Manning and Schütze,

it claims that

> The probability P(R|d,q) that a document is relevant derives from the probability of relevance of the terms vector of that document P(R|x,q). By using the Bayes rule we get:

$P(R|x,q) = \dfrac{P(x|R,q)P(R|q)}{P(x|q)}$

Now, Bayes rule is as follows:
$P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$

If you set $A := R$ and $B := x,q$ you get:
$P(A|B) = P(R|x,q) = \dfrac{P(x,q|R)P(R)}{P(x,q)}$

If you compare the terms, you'll notice why I am confused:

- $x=x,q$
- $R,q=q$
- $R|q=R$
- $x|q=x,q$

This result has nothing to do with the initial claim.
I think that I miss the definition of the 'comma' in this context. I am not aware of multi-dimensional probabilities. As I understand, a probability $P$ is always defined over a $\sigma$ algebra of an event space $\Omega$

In order to understand what's the idea behind the formula above, here a few things that could help:

- What does the comma  *precisely* mean in the formula above (in mathematical notation)?
- What is the underlying $\Omega$ ? If there is a probability $P$, then there must be an Omega $\Omega$ which serves as the space on which we define probabilities. It's not clear at all what this space is. If a document is a vector $x \in \{{0,1}\}^n$ and the query is a vector $q \in \{{0,1}\}^n$, then defining a space like $\Omega := \{{0,1}\}^n \times \{{0,1}\}^n$ could make sense. In this case it's not clear what $R$ is. Maybe the intent is to use $\Omega := \{{0,1}\}^n \times \{{0,1}\}^n \times \{{relevant, nonrelevant}\}$
- Do $R$, $x$ or $q$ have anything to do with random variables? If yes, then it would help to see their domain, e.g: $R : \Omega \mapsto {0,1}  $
- Because the conditional probability is defined between 2 sets, $R$ and $x,q$, as well as $x$ and $R,q$ or $R|q$ should represent sets. If $R$ is a random variable, then maybe in the formula above the term $R$ represents the set $\{\omega \in \Omega\ | R(\omega)=relevant\}$. What is then the set for $x$ or for $q$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to talk about x, q and R as (random) events - set of outcomes of the random experiment. x and q will be one element sets but R is an event denoting x is relevant to q and thus it is a subset of cartesian product X x Q (pair of a document and a query).

Comma is then set conjunction and P(A,B) = P(A ^ B) which equals to P(A) * P(B) when A is independent of B.

The wiki statement 'by using Bayesian rule' is a bit of a shortcut since you need to apply it several times. To derive the above formula for P(R|x,q), I would start with conditional probability definition (which is the root of Bayesian rule):

P(A|B) = P(A ^ B) / P(B)

Then:

P(R|x,q) = P(R ^ x ^ q) / P(x,q) = P(x|R,q) * P(R,q) / [ P(x|q) * P(q) ] =

= P(x|R,q) * P(R|q) / P(q) / [ P(x|q) * P(q) ]

When you divide nominator and denominator by P(q), you obtain

P(R|x,q) = P(x|R,q) * P(R|q) / P(x|q)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for this explanation. It's indeed what is missing to precisely undestand the formula.